# Passing a value via named pipes in c

Tags: c, operating-system

I have this code that creates 3 child processes from a father. For each child, I have an array `pid[i]` that has -1 values for every `i != i (number)` of the child so I can isolate each child code using `if(pid[i]==0)`. First child passes value 1 to second child. Second child computes `1*2` and passes it to third child and third child computes `(1*2)*3`.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int mkfifo(const char *path, mode_t mode);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd,rec,recs;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    pid_t pid[4];
    pid[1]=fork();
    if(pid[1]==0){
        pid[2]=-1;
        pid[3]=-1;
             }
    if(pid[1]>0){
       pid[2]=fork();
       if(pid[2]==0){
          pid[1]=-1;
          pid[3]=-1;
       }
         if(pid[2]>0){
           pid[3]=fork();
           if(pid[3]==0){
              pid[1]=-1;
              pid[2]=-1;
           }
             }
    wait(0);
    }

    if(pid[1]==0){
      rec=1;
      fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
      write(fd, &rec, sizeof(rec));
      close(fd);
    }
    if(pid[2]==0){
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(fd, &recs, sizeof(recs));
        rec=recs*2;
        printf(" passed value is %d \n",rec);
        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, &rec, sizeof(rec));
        close(fd);
    }
    if(pid[3]==0){
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(fd, &recs, sizeof(recs));
        rec=recs*3;
        printf(" passed value is %d \n",rec);
        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, &rec, sizeof(rec));
        close(fd);
    }
}
```

I expect this program to print:

```
passed value is 2
passed value is 6
```

However I get different results every time I run it (it may produce the right result). Why is this happening and how can I control this?

Comment: First of all indent your code properly.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am sorry i edited it.